Can't run "node index.js" due to a syntaxError
My code is the following;

import express from "express";

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.listen(port, () =>{
    console.log(`Server is running on ${port}.`)
});


I don't understand what the issue is here. I'm following a course and followed the suggested steps yet I don't really know how to fix this.
node index.js
     ^^^^^
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'index'

I thought it was a syntax error in the code but I can't find anything. Error makes it sounds like it doesn't like the name 'index' which I thought was funny.
I ran npm install express, then node, node index.js. Nothing super complex, is it possible the course is outdated and some syntax here is no longer valid? (Relatively new to coding, mainly in javascript!)

Where did you type node index.js? That's a command that makes sense in certain environments (command prompt) but no sense elsewhere.

Right.  If you tell us the operating system and the editor/IDE you are using, we can advise you how to bring up a command shell to run this.

I apologize this is my first post, I'm using Windows 11, Visual studio code and I'm running node index.js into the VSC's terminal which is bash. I ran this command for other projects and didn't have issues.

The error message suggests you entered node index.js from inside node.
PS C:\git\foo> node
Welcome to Node.js v20.11.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
> node index.js
node index.js
     ^^^^^

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'index'
>

You should first exit node, then from the regular command prompt (bash, PowerShell, cmd.exe), enter node index.js.
node without arguments brings you in the REPL, which is an interactive JavaScript interpreter. It only understands JavaScript plus a handful of special commands. "node index.js" is not a valid JavaScript command, hence the error. What you can do is load and run index.js with the .load command.
PS C:\temp> cat index.js
console.log('Hello world');
PS C:\temp> node
Welcome to Node.js v20.11.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
> .help
.break    Sometimes you get stuck, this gets you out
.clear    Alias for .break
.editor   Enter editor mode
.exit     Exit the REPL
.help     Print this help message
.load     Load JS from a file into the REPL session
.save     Save all evaluated commands in this REPL session to a file

Press Ctrl+C to abort current expression, Ctrl+D to exit the REPL
> .load index.js
console.log('Hello world');

Hello world
undefined
> .exit
PS C:\temp>

See also:
https://nodejs.org/en/learn/command-line/how-to-use-the-nodejs-repl

I see, I thought that you had to run node first and then run node index.js, are you supposed to just run the latter immediately, and node is just for checking the version/help?

node is the actual process that will read/execute JavaScript. node with no args opens essentially a "JavaScript console" for you to input what you wish (like a browser console). With arguments, node will instead execute the given script. There's documentation around the node command and its arguments

@Mal I edited my answer to explain how this could have worked from inside node. Hope it helps clarify things. Other programming environments (e.g. Python and Perl) have something similar.

I heavily appreciate you guys clarifying, thank you very much! I understand what you two mean, I figured it was a console that did it all and had to be activated first, but this explains the error then.
